# Add a static block right under the main navigation, not wrapped in a widget, full width

Tags: magento2, layout, blocks, static-block

I'm using Magento 2 with Luma theme, and I'm trying to add a block on the home page only, right under the main navigation, and I want to do it without any margin or padding, full width, basically not in a wrapper. 
The problem is that if I create the block and then add it into a widget, the widget css class has a max-width and some padding, and I don't want to force that css class. There is a proper way to add that block to the page, not wrapped in that widget class?

Answer (score 1):

Create new `cms_index_index.xml` in your theme

> /app/design/frontend/Vendor/YourTheme/Magento_Cms/layout/cms_index_index.xml

**Add below code in xml file :**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
    <referenceBlock name="page.top">
        <block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" name="test_cmsblock" after='catalog.topnav'>
            <arguments>
                <argument name="block_id" xsi:type="string">test_cmsblock</argument>
            </arguments>
        </block>
    </referenceBlock>
</body>
</page>
```

Comment: Is that working for you ?

Comment: Is above solution works for you please vote and accept so another person use same :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your theme `default.xml` file -

```
<referenceBlock name="page.top">
            <block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" name="block_identifier" after='catalog.topnav'>
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="block_id" xsi:type="string">below-navigation-block</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>    
        </referenceBlock>
```